Can I install miniforge3 in Windows 11 PC using pyenv-win?
I usually use Mac and I have installed miniforge3 using pyenv. Now I get a new Windows 11 PC and I want to install miniforge3 using pyenv-win, if possible.
After installing pyenv-win using Chocoratey, I executed the following command.
pyenv install --list


However, I couldn't find any miniforge3 version in the list, unlike pyenv for Mac. Is there any way to install miniforge3 using pyenv-win in Windows PC, or is it impossible?
